# how to create dropdown from a hash in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, hash, drop-down-menu

**In rails 3, how to create a Dropdown from hash**

I have following code in my User class

```
class User
  ...   other codes
  key :gender, Integer    # i use mongo db

  class << self
    def genders()
      genders = {
        '1' => 'Male',
        '2' => 'Female',
        '3' => 'Secret'
      }
    end
  end

end
```

In the user form, i am trying to create a gender dropdown list

```
<%= f.collection_select nil, :gender, User.genders, :key, :value %>
```

but it complain

```
undefined method `merge' for :value:Symbol
```

So what is the proper way to create the dropdown?

Thanks

Comment: Why `nil` as first argument to `collection_select`?

Comment: i dont know.. i read from the api doc...and some blog article do thing like that..i just copy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work:

```
<%= f.collection_select :gender, User.genders, :first, :last %>
```

**Edit**: Explanations:

[`collection_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select) will call [`each`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerator.html#M000300) on the object you give (`User.genders` here) and the two methods (`first` and `last` here) on each object. It's roughly equivalent to something like this:

```
User.genders.each do |object|
  output << "<option value=#{object.first.inspect}>#{h object.last}</option>"
end
```

When you call [`each` on a Hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M000742), it yields an [`Array`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html) of two values (the key and the value). These values can be retreived with the `first` and `last` methods.

Comment: Hi Michael, it is working ..... but why to_arry will help???  can you explain a little bit..coz i am new to ruby...

Comment: Actually it doesn't because Hash has an `each` method. I removed it and added a some explanations.

Comment: It worked for me, but I had to make sure that the symbol of the first argument (:gender in the example), had an entry under my models :attr_accessor. Thank you for your answer...