# Rails select form helpers not playing nice with my hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, form-helpers

I would like to update the `Transaction` object's `status` attribute in my edit form. Status should be a drop down list where I get to select a text value correlated with an integer value that is actually PATCHed to the object.

In other words, I have a variable that looks like this:

```
@statuscodes = [
{ "Working" => 1 },
{ "In progress" => 2 },
{ "Cancelled: No response from borrower" => 3  },
{ "Cancelled: No response from lender" => 4 },
{ "Cancelled: Time period too long" => 5 },
...
]
```

Following the docs and some other SO posts, I've tried both a `f.select` and a `f.collection_select` in what I believe to be the right syntax. Obviously not, and I've printed the errors for each that follow. Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

```
<%= f.select :transaction, :status, options_for_select(@statuscodes), {include_blank: true} %>
<!-- undefined method `merge' for #<ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer:0x007fd9da299300> -->

<%= f.collection_select :transaction, :status, @statuscodes, :last, :first, {include_blank: true} %>
<!-- undefined method `merge' for :first:Symbol -->

<%= f.select :transaction, :status, @statuscodes, {include_blank: true} %>
<!-- undefined method `merge' for #<Array:0x007fd9e1381b30> -->
```

Comment: It should be just `<%= f.select :status, options_for_select(@statuscodes), {include_blank: true} %>`

Comment: Can you check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659826/how-to-create-dropdown-from-a-hash-in-rails-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
<%= f.collection_select :status, @statuscodes[0], :last, :first, {include_blank: true} %>
```

Please note that the second argument should be either a `hash` or `array of objects` on which methods provided in 3rd and 4th argument can be called.

Comment: Everyone is right... I didn't need the `:transaction`, but also, my `@statuscodes` were declared incorrectly. I had it as an array of individual hashes because I'm tired I guess... rather than an actual Hash!